# why i am having python39.dll file missing if I installed python 3.8. 7

Tags: python

I installed python 3.9 at first, but I wanted to use TensorFlow so I deleted and install python 3.8.7 and it worked out. But now every time I try to run <python --version> command it says that there is a python39.dll missing even though I have my python38.dll file already

Comment: How did you uninstall previous python version? Did you use operating system mechanisms or just deleted the folder?

Comment: Also, please check, what python folder is specified in the system PATH environment variable. And check this folder contents.

Comment: In general, there is no need to remove older versions of Python to use newer versions. You should start using some form of virtual environments to manage this, either using `virtualenv` or `conda`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I resolved the problem just by uninstalling every python program on the computer and reinstalling everything, I'm not quite sure what was causing that error but now everything is alright.

Comment: I'm glad you got it worked out! That doesn't really answer the question, though, so it would be better as a comment than as an answer.